# Cannot read property 'asObservable' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am building a search function over a JSON API and I am getting this error:

#### Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'asObservable' of undefined

I'm not familiar with angular and can't seem to find the problem.

productService.ts

```
import { Observable, of, Subscription, Subject } from "rxjs";



searchResults = new Subject<Product[]>();

searchProduct(term: string): Subscription {
      console.log('Service is searching: ' + term );
      return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.searchURL + term).subscribe(
        results => this.searchResult.next(results));

    }

    getSearchResult(): Observable<Product[]> {
      return this.searchResult.asObservable();
    }
```

component.ts

```
 searchResult: Product[];

 constructor(
         private productService:ProductService,
         private router: Router
    ) { 
      this.productService.getSearchResult().subscribe(results => {
          this.searchResult = results;
        })

    }
```

Comment: Your service doesn't have any property named `searchResult`. It seems to have one named `searchResults`. But that is partial code, and I'm surprised it even compiles. Post your actual code, otherwise we have to guess what the rest of the code can be, and what is an actual mistake and what is not.

Comment: Thanks. As always, stupid typos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Subject in productService.ts is called `searchResults`, but your `getSearchResult` function in the service returns `this.searchResult` (likely a typo).